# Google Calender API for requesting other user's calender access

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar in my application. I want to send request to another user for accessing their calendar.

I tried Google Calendar API. But I couldn't find an API to send request.  I am able to get free/busy details from shared calendars. 
Is it possible to send request through API?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)? Then you can try to [delegate authority to authenticate users to your service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried using service account, But didn't find any api to send request to another user for accessing their calender.

Comment: Hi, i want to subscribe calender functionality..